# Books/tutorials about Clojure's state related issues

Tags: clojure

I'm interested in the state management part of Clojure, but most books and tutorials seem to focus on its LISP-ness.

Can you recommend a tutorial or book that gives examples and analysis on refs, vars and friends. I know there are some pages about these at clojure.org but they are a bit too terse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The Joy of Clojure](http://joyofclojure.com/) contains a whole chapter titled *Mutation*, which deals with Clojure's concurrency primitives.  It's pretty comprehensive.

Answer (score 5):

This [article](http://java.ociweb.com/mark/stm/article.html) is quite a comprehensive discussion of all the details around the various pieces of shared state management available in Clojure. It's quite old (refers to Clojure 1.0), but the higher level parts are still valid.

Answer (score 2):

The Hickey-Talk "Are we there yet" is worth looking at (the relevant part starts at minute 50): http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Are-We-There-Yet-Rich-Hickey

Comment: This one actually got me interested in Clojure! Now I'm looking for something more.